# User-defined literals as variadic templates

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

GCC 4.7.2 seems to have variadic-char-templated literal operators only implemented for numbers:

```
template<char... chars>
constexpr size_t operator "" _size() { return sizeof...(chars); }

int main()
{
    std::cout << 42_size;    // (1) works
    std::cout << "foo"_size; // (2) does not
}
```

- Is there a version of GCC that supports this code?
- Is (2) even part of the standard?

Comment: (2) is not part of the standard.... unfortunately. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.14.8.5 of C++11 standard declares

> If L is a user-defined-string-literal, let str be the literal without
>   its ud-suffix and let len be the number of code units in str (i.e.,
>   its length excluding the terminating null character). The literal L is
>   treated as a call of the form operator "" X (str, len)

So rewrite your code as:

```
#include <iostream>

// (1)
template<char... chars>
constexpr size_t operator "" _size() { return sizeof...(chars); }

// (2)
constexpr size_t operator "" _size( const char* str, size_t sz ) { return sz; }

int
main(void)
{
  std::cout << 42_size << std::endl;    // (1)
  std::cout << "foo"_size << std::endl; // (2)

  return 0;
}
```

To explicitly specify correct form for (2)

Comment: Sad to hear that. I was about to perform some serious black magic using decltype and literal operators to allow string literals as template arguments... Well, no type-safe compile-time printf for me then.